# How to get valid base64 string for an image

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios7

I use the following code to get a base64 encoded string of my image:

```
UIImage *image = [photoView image];
NSString *encoded = [UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];
```

The image is 800*800 pixels, but the generated string is so big that it crashes my browser when I paste it in a textbox. I pasted it in dreamweaver to count the lines and it is over 300.000 lines. This can't be right. If I upload the same picture to [this site](http://www.askapache.com/online-tools/base64-image-converter/) it generates a base64 string of about 200 lines.

How do I generate a 'normal' base64 string in objective c? One that I can actually use...

As Martin R suggested I checked the data length of what UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) returns and it is 4502370 bytes. This is probably a part of the problem. Could it be that drawing an image in a UIImageView and retrieving it later like I'm doing gives back an image at the screen size?

Comment: You can try: UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.9f)

Comment: Why don't you start with `NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)` and check `[data length]` to isolate the problem?

Comment: … so it is *not* a problem of the Base64 encoder.

Comment: @MartinR Indeed, I'm retrieving the image from the camera and than I rescale it, but it seems like it isn't rescaled correctly. image.size is downscaled properly to 800*800, but the data length is increased after rescaling....

Comment: Any difference you're seeing is likely a difference in compression.

Answer (score 2):

By using `NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength` you limit each line to 64 characters (as is written in the documentation). Try:

```
NSString *encoded = [UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
```

Comment: I did that to count the number of lines, I used NSDataBase64EncodingEndLineWithCarriageReturn before. I will try with 0 now.

Answer (score 0):

A base-64 encoded string is 1.37 times the size of the binary data. Therefore:

800x800x4 (32-bit RGBA) = 2,560,000 bytes

x 1.37 = 3,507,200 bytes

I don't understand why you are pasting the base-64 encoded string into a browser though?

Comment: I'm pasting it in a base64 decoder online to see if I succeeded.

Comment: `UIImagePNGRepresentation()` returns the PNG data, not the raw data. But of course, if the image compresses poorly, that might be similarly large.

Comment: Of course, PNG is supposedly compressed, though the amount of compression highly variable.

Comment: @MartinR Sure, the point being is that resulting string will always be too big to paste anywhere you please.

Comment: And it's not immediately clear what kind of image compression is occurring on the site the OP mentions.

Comment: @trojanfoe base64 encoding a 800*800 image online results in a very small string compared to mine, so there must be some error in my code.

Comment: @Kevin - What flavor of image file is produced?