# Image uploading to server

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to send image and param to server, image should in base64 format.

Ex : my url : http://.............

Parameters: image = image (base64 format),  filename = my image name

I tried with NSURLSessions, image sent to server but image bytes is ZERO.

my code is:

```
UIImage *dataImage = [UIImage imageWithData:strImageBase64];
NSString *ImageBase64 = [UIImagePNGRepresentation(dataImage) base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];

NSURLSessionConfiguration *defaultConfigObject = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSURLSession *defaultSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration: defaultConfigObject delegate: nil delegateQueue: [NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];

NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:myurl];
NSMutableURLRequest * urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSString * params = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"image=%@&filename=%@",ImageBase64,@"unique2.png"];
[urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[urlRequest setHTTPBody:[params dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSURLSessionDataTask * dataTask =[defaultSession dataTaskWithRequest:urlRequest
                                                   completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

                                                       NSLog(@"Response:%@ %@\n", response, error);
                                                       if(error == nil)
                                                       {
                                                           NSString * text = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                                                           NSLog(@"Data = %@",text);
                                                       }
                                                   }];
[dataTask resume];
```

Comment: are you saying that text is nil ?

Comment: Why are you using `NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength`? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20971719/how-to-get-valid-base64-string-for-an-image

Comment: What are the values of (`data`, `response`, `error`) in the completion block? What do you receive on the server (filename but 0byte image)?

Comment: server side image data is zero bytes (no image data , 0 bytes)